# Side Bar menu implementation setting root View controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, xib, sidebar

I m using https://github.com/ccabanero/ios-sidebar-menu but can't find how can I set the root view controller for it.I already maintain a login/signup screen and a tabBar .i want side bar to show after the login with my homepage .I m not using navigation controller,what can i do to achieve this[here how i declared it in AppDelegate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhEfB.png)

Comment: u want open menu bar after login screen right ?

Comment: yes as like my tab bar...appears

Comment: then open programatically your menubar after Login Succsess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you switch to a more recent library that is maintained. The one you're using was last updated 2 years ago.

Check out `ViewDeck`: https://github.com/ViewDeck/ViewDeck